# C# dllで表示したフォームをシャットダウン時に閉じたい

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

一般的には、フォームを立ち上げていても、ログオフやシャットダウンをすれば
一緒に閉じるものなのですが、単体起動するフォームのアプリをdllにし、
別のアプリから参照してdll化したフォームを立ち上げると、ログオフ、及び
シャットダウンしたときには親フォームはきちんと閉じるのに、dll化した
アプリの方が閉じずに、『このアプリが再起動を妨げています。』のような
メッセージが出て、シャットダウンが止まってしまいます。

そのため、ネットで調べ、下記のイベントを実装して、シャットダウン、ログオフを
しようとしたときに、併せてフォームが閉じるようにしようとしたのですが、これでも駄目。

```
//ログオフ、シャットダウンしようとしているとき
private void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
{
        Application.Exit();
}
```

ちなみに、dll化したフォームはデジタル時計を作ったアプリで、Timerで
一秒ごとフォームを再描画する仕様のものですが、それが何かの原因なのでしょうか？
このフォームは、単体のexeのままなら、きちんとシャットダウン時に閉じてくれます。

原因と対策をご指導いただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

追記・すみません。原因の探り方が甘かったみたいです。
試してみたところ、原因はdll化した方ではなく、呼び出している親アプリの方でした。
一度、ゼロからフォームを立ち上げて、そこに時計のdllフォームを呼び出せば、無事
シャットダウンに併せてクローズ、しかし、空のフォームをdll化して既存の親のアプリで
呼び出すと、時計の時と同じように再起動を妨げました。
dllは一切問題はないようです。確認の方法が不足しており、申し訳ありませんでした。

さて、そこで親元のアプリの方ですが、クローズボタンを押しても終了させず、
最小化させて、タスクトレイに常駐、アプリの終了はCotentMenuStripのメニューから
『終了』を選ぶことで、Application.Exit()を呼び出して終了させる流れを作っています。

これが原因になっているのでしょうか。

更に追記・どうも原因がいろいろと重なっているらしく、親アプリの方でFormClisingで
クローズをキャンセルするとシャットダウンの時にも終了されることがないようです。
しかし、シャットダウン時の例の警告画面には親アプリの名前は出てきません。どういうわけか、
親、子とも閉じられていないのに警告は子供のみ表示されるようです。

また、クローズをキャンセルすることで、上記SystemEvents_SessionEndingも
実行されないようです。

更に問題は、例のシャットダウンの警告画面がSystemEvents_SessionEndingメソッドが
走るより前に表示されてしまうため、たとえこのメソッドでクローズさせようとしても
もう遅いということです(Windows10にて)。

初めの表題の内容とは意味合いが異なってしまいましたが、システムのシャットダウン時に、
親アプリがきちんと終了させられれば解決できそうですが、
そういった方法はありますでしょうか。

何度も申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: dll化は関係ありません。ログオフやシャットダウン時だけの問題でしょうか？ フォーム右上の×ボタンでは閉じることはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 早速のご連絡、ありがとうございます。

該当のデジタル時計フォームは、現在はBorderStyleをNoneにしていますが、
一度フォーム有(Sizable)に戻しても、現象は発生します。

もちろん、きちんとクローズできますし、単体でならシャットダウン時に閉じてくれます。

Comment: 時計フォームの×ボタンで閉じるのは当然です。アプリ側の×ボタンで時計フォームが閉じるかどうかが問題です。閉じなかった場合はデバッガーをアタッチしどのような状態になっているかを確認できます。

Comment: 何度もありがとうございます。

ご指摘の通り、問題はdll側ではなく、親アプリの砲でした。
そこで、その後もいろいろと試してみたのですが、いまだに解決策がつかめません。
引き続き、ご助力いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 通常はメインフォームを閉じるとアプリケーションは終了します。終了させないためにどのような手段を取っているのか（及びタスクトレイから終了させるにはどのような手段を取っているのか）に依存してくると思います。フォームを閉じずに `Form.Hide()` してしまうなどいくつか方法があると思います。

Comment: すみません、お礼が遅れてしまいました。
結局のところ、原因も特定できずじまいで、いまだに解決できずにいます。
色々試してみて、何か方法を見つけてみようと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 重複候補: [C# シャットダウン、再起動時に子のフォームが閉じないで残ってしまう](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17621/c-%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a3%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%83%80%e3%82%a6%e3%83%b3-%e5%86%8d%e8%b5%b7%e5%8b%95%e6%99%82%e3%81%ab%e5%ad%90%e3%81%ae%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a0%e3%81%8c%e9%96%89%e3%81%98%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7%e6%ae%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86)

Comment: 練り直して再投稿されたようなものですし、こちらの投稿を残しておく意義も薄いかと思います。よって重複クローズではなく削除を考えています。

Comment: @unarist おっしゃる通り削除の方が良いですね

Answer (score 1):

Timer はメインスレッドではないスレッドで Elapsed をコールします。
そのため、もし Elapsed イベントハンドラ内で単純にその外部フォームを表示しているようでしたら、そのフォームはメッセージループのないフォームになってしまい、終了その他のイベントに応答できなくなりそうです。（ここらへんの結果的挙動は調べないと自信がありませんが。）

現状、フォーム表示のために Elapsed イベント内で特になにもしていないようであれば、[マーシャリングの質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709187/accessing-ui-in-a-thread)などを参考に、UIスレッド上でフォームを作成するようにするとよいと思います。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。

本文に追記しました通り、どうやら子のdll側には何の問題もないようです。
ご指摘いただいたElapsedなどには、特に何もいじってはいないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

SystemEvent.SessionEndingイベントがUIスレッドで発生しない可能性がある場合は、次のように対処できます。

```
private void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e){
    if( Application.OpenForms.Count > 0 ){
        var mainForm = Application.OpenForms[0];
        if( mainForm.InvokeRequired )
            mainForm.Invoke( new Action( Application.Exit ) );
        else
            Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FormClosing` イベントにて `FormClosingEventArgs` の `Cancel` プロパティを `false` にするといいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

ここで示されているフォームは、親ですか、dllですか？

Comment: FormClosedイベントがこないフォームの方です。更新された質問を見るに親の方だと思います。

Answer (score 0):

FormClosing の FormClosingEventArgs e.CloseReason の値で判定できませんか？ 
CloseReason.WindowsShutDown, CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing 以外の時は最小化・タスクトレイ常駐・Cancel=Trueする 
(質問に記載の要件だけであれば CloseReason.WindowsShutDown以外の時だけでもいいかもしれません )