# C# シャットダウン、再起動時に子のフォームが閉じないで残ってしまう

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

前回、dllでのフォームが閉じないという内容で投げた質問の続きになります。
その時は、はっきりと原因を突き止めずに質問をしてしまい、大変申し訳ありませんでした。

やろうとしていることは、前回と同じです。
アプリのフォームが立ち上がっているときに、Windowsのシャットダウン、あるいは
再起動をかけるると、アプリの子供のフォームが消えずに残ってしまい、SDや再起動を
妨げてしまうのを解決する方法です。

前回は自分でdllだからかと思ってしまいましたが、回答者様が指摘していただいたとおり、
dll云々は関係ありませんでした。

メインのフォームでやっていることは、タスクトレイ常駐型のアプリを作ろうとしているため、
クローズボタンでは閉じず、タスクトレイのアイコンを右クリックで表示されるコンテキスト
メニューの『閉じる』選択で、Application.Exit()で終了させています。
しかし、SD、及び再起動時に、メインのフォームは最小化するだけ、子供として呼び出した
フォームは閉じずに残り、再起動などを妨げます。また、一度再起動をキャンセルし、
もう一度シャットダウンをしても、やはり同じように残り続けます。
メインフォームは閉じられませんが、再起動を妨げたりしません。

下記に、必要と思われる全コードを掲示します。

再度お手数をおかけすることになると思いますが、何卒ご助力をお願いいたします。

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ResidentForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //　問題の閉じないフォーム。ただ単純なフォームです。
        private Form3 f = new Form3();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SystemEvents.SessionEnding +=
                new SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);
        }



        private void tsmiQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false; // アイコンをトレイから取り除く
            Application.Exit(); // アプリケーションの終了
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = true; // フォームの表示
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; // 最小化をやめる
            }
            this.Activate(); // フォームをアクティブにする
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall
              //　追記しました
              || e.CloseReason != CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutDown
            )
            {
                e.Cancel = true; // フォームが閉じるのをキャンセル
                this.Visible = false; // フォームの非表示
            }
        }

        //ログオフ、シャットダウンしようとしているとき
        private void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.Logoff || e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown)
            {
                this.f.Hide();
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void SlideshowBackForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            //イベントを解放する
            SystemEvents.SessionEnding -=
                new SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.f.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}

namespace ResidentForm
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 必要なデザイナー変数です。
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// 使用中のリソースをすべてクリーンアップします。
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">マネージ リソースが破棄される場合 true、破棄されない場合は false です。</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows フォーム デザイナーで生成されたコード

        /// <summary>
        /// デザイナー サポートに必要なメソッドです。このメソッドの内容を
        /// コード エディターで変更しないでください。
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);
            this.contextMenuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
            this.tsmiQuit = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.contextMenuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // notifyIcon1
            // 
            this.notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
            this.notifyIcon1.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon1.Icon")));
            this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            this.notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);
            // 
            // contextMenuStrip1
            // 
            this.contextMenuStrip1.ImageScalingSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.tsmiQuit});
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Name = "contextMenuStrip1";
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(115, 30);
            // 
            // tsmiQuit
            // 
            this.tsmiQuit.Name = "tsmiQuit";
            this.tsmiQuit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(114, 26);
            this.tsmiQuit.Text = "終了";
            this.tsmiQuit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tsmiQuit_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 253);
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
            this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Shown);
            this.contextMenuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem tsmiQuit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `FormClosing`で`CloseReason.WindowsShutDown`他を無視しているのが気になります

Comment: [前スレッドでコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/15163/c-dll%E3%81%A7%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E9%96%89%E3%81%98%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84#comment14805_15163)した通りですね。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
いただいた条件文を追加しましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。
sayuriさんからの、Hideにするというのもやってみたのですが、
解決にはつながりませんでした。何度もお手数をおかけして、
本当に申し訳ありません。

Comment: @たたぱた 「終了させないためにどのような手段を取っているのか」という私からの問いに対する答えが、本スレッド質問文にある`Form1_FormClosing()`ハンドラになるかと。
そしてそれに対する皆さんの回答が、`CloseReason.WindowsShutDown`までも拒否しているためにシャットダウンできないだけ、となります。

Comment: 何度もすみません。
お察しの通りです。再起動時などの画面で、フォームが妨げているのかと
思っていましたが、再起動をさせないからフォームも閉じないということでした。
しかし、正直なところ、再起動時の画面を見れば、混乱してしまいますね。
本当にすみません。ですが助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

前の質問にも回答しましたがFormClosing の e.CloseReason の条件に (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)も追加してください。
これを加えないとシャットダウンの時もe.Cancel=Trueにしているので SystemEvents_SessionEndingイベントが発生しなくなってるような気がします。

なんかe.Cancel=trueにするのは UserClosingのみでいい気がします。
FormOwnerClosingとかもフォローする必要がありそうなので。
また子フォームが閉じないのであれば明示的にClose()するとか。

```
if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Visible = false;
}else{
    this.f.close();
}
```

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。

いただいたとおりに条件を追加してみましたが、特に変化はなく、
同じ状況になりました。私もまた一つ勘違いしていましたが、どうやら
親元のフォームも閉じていませんでした。
引き続きご助力いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: orではなくandで条件追加してください。orだと必ずTrueになります。

Comment: ブレイクポイントやログを書くなどして、どのような順番でイベントが発生するか動作をきちんと確認した方がよいと思います。

Comment: すみませんでした。
ご指摘の通りです。andで条件を付け加えたところ、無事に終了できました。
『子のフォームが閉じないためにシャットダウンできない』のではなく、
『シャットダウンしないからフォームも閉じない』ということだったようです。
もっと下調べをして質問するべきでした。
ありがとうございました。